# Print certain cluster in R

Tags: r

I am doing k-means clustering and I have this:

```
d$cluster <- res_c$cluster
d[1:20, c("cluster", "Region", "2016(Total)")
```

to print 20 elements with their clusters, how can I print only elements of certain cluster?

Comment: Example cluster 1: `d[d$cluster == 1, c("cluster", "Region", "2016(Total)")]`

Answer (score 0):

> cluster_no = 2 #The cluster you want

Method 1:

> > d[which(d$cluster == cluster_no),]

Method 2:

> library(dplyr)
>
> d %>% filter(cluster==cluster_no)